# "Create" View for parent-child relationship MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, parent-child

So i have this model:

```
 public class Subthing
 {
     public virtual int SubthingId { get; set; }
     public virtual int ThingId { get; set; }

     public virtual string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
     public virtual Subthing Parent { get; set; }
     public virtual List<Subthing> Childs { get; set; }

     public virtual Thing Thing{ get; set; }
}
```

And i want to make a create view for introducing subthings related to subthings. I have this controller:

```
public ActionResult CriarMoreSubthings(int id)
        {

            var x = db.Subthings.FirstOrDefault(e => e.SubthingId == id);

            if (x == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var subthing = new Subthing()
            {
                ThingId = x.ThingId,
                ParentId = id //(also tried x.SubthingId)
            };

            return View("CriarMoreSubthings", subthing);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CriarMoreSubthings(Subthing subthing)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Subthings.Add(subthing);
                db.SaveChanges();              
                return RedirectToAction(blabla);
            }

            return View(subthing);
        }
```

But it always create with the parentId = 0, but the parentId should be the subthing id. (For the record, it can be all wrong, i already searched a lot about this but i can't make it work, novice here). What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean its `0` in the POST method? Did you include a hidden input for it in the view?

Comment: When i finish creating, i check the database and the ParentId field is always 0. But it was what you said, i didn't have the hidden input for the ParentId. Problem solved, thanks